# Recurrence Relation for Deterministic Selection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, selection, recurrence, divide-and-conquer, quickselect

Linear time deterministic algorithm exists for selection. I read this [link](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960130.html) and the recurrence for a divide and conquer approach looks like: T(n) <= 12n/5 + T(n/5) + T(7n/10)

However, I don't understand why must it be T(7n/10). The link itself has mentioned that each half of the partition has size (3n/10), so the algorithm recurses on (6n/10). Even if we include the 5 elements from the group of the median of medians, the recursion is on (6n/10+5). I do understand that 7n/10 is a valid upper bound on the size of the recursion, but isn't it too weak an upper bound here?

Comment: But these are counted in the two partitions of (3/10n) already.

Comment: If you walk through the algorithm, it's implied. Since 3n/10 means each median element plus 2 elements in that group.

Answer (score 0):

The `7n/10` is not the result of `3n/10 + 3n/10 + n/10`; it comes from doing `n - 3n/10`.

From the link:

> It's easier to talk about this in terms of the elements thrown away (not included in the call).

The argument is that the recursive call is made on a shorter list formed by *not* including some elements. By showing that *at least* `3n/10` elements are excluded from the list, it follows that *at most* `7n/10` elements are included, and that bound is tight because the `3n/10` bound is tight.

So, it's shown that L1 and L3 both have size at least `3n/10` by showing that they each contain at least 3 elements from each of `n/10` subsets; then one of L1 or L3 is excluded from the recursive call, giving the result. Since only one of L1 or L3 is excluded - not both - it would not make sense to add their sizes together.